# Scraping Zip+4 from USPS

Tags: vba, excel, internet-explorer, web-scraping

I am trying to make a simple spreadsheet that will take addresses and look up the +4 zip from the USPS website. I have done this with success, but the results seem to be inconsistent. I can run this code one time and it will work great and other time it will not return the +4.  Is there a more efficient way of writing this?

```
Sub ZipCodeSearch()
Dim objIE As InternetExplorer
Dim result As String



'start IE and Navigate to USPS

    Set objIE = New InternetExplorer
    objIE.Visible = True
    objIE.navigate "https://tools.usps.com/go/ZipLookupAction_input"

   'Wait for the website to load
       Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop

    'Fill in Street Address
        objIE.document.getElementById("tAddress").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A2")
    'Fill in City
        objIE.document.getElementById("tCity").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("B2")


    'Fill in State-Need to figure out how to select the roller.
        'objIE.document.getElementById("select-frame").Value = Sheets("Sheet1").Range("C1")


    'Click the find Button
        objIE.document.getElementById("lookupZipFindBtn").Click

    'Wait on Search
        Do While objIE.Busy = True Or objIE.readyState <> 4: DoEvents: Loop
    'Get Reslts)
        For Each aEle In objIE.document.getElementsByClassName("zip4")
            result = aEle

     'Put Results in Worksheet
             Sheets("Sheet1").Range("E2").Value = aEle.innerText
                Debug.Print aEle.innerText
        Next
     'Quit Internet Explore
     objIE.Quit
```

Comment: When it fails does the IE page look any different from what you'd expect?

Comment: No, the IE page looks exactly the same.  It just fails to grab the Zip+4 and place it in the cell.

Comment: When the code fails, inspect the webpage and verify that there actually exists a `zip4` DOM class in the source.